# How to make multiple tr function in JavaScript/Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-events

I am working with Rails, and using JavaScript as well. I am having trouble getting Javascript function for the multiple tr in my table. I am using bootstrap to display my modal and everything works fine for the first tr, but it doesn't function for the others:

```
  <script type = "text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $("#btn-show-modal").click(function(e){

      $("#dialogue-example").modal('show');

    });
    $("#btn-close-modal").click(function(c){
      $("#dialogue-example").modal('hide');

    });
  });
  </script>



<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Brand</th>
      <th>description</th>
      <th>Rate</th>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <tr id ="btn-show-modal">

        <td><%= product.brand %></td>
        <td><%= product.short_description %></td>
        <td><%= product.rate_amount %></td>
        <td><%= product.created_at %></td>
          <% name = product.name %>
          <% description = product.description %>
      </tr>



  </tbody>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: IDs are unique (and can be only used on one element), use classes instead.

Comment: You're absolut correct Benjamin. Make it an answer. I would but you were first.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I will select it as a answer.

Answer (score 0):

[@BenjaminGruenbaum wrote in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat):

> IDs are unique (and can be only used on one element), use classes instead.